# How to determine which type of web service(soap or rest) by looking project

Tags: java, rest, web-services, soap

I am a newbie to Java and started learning webservices,my question is how one determines whether the project is written using soap or rest ?? Can we use spring framework to write webservices ??  Can anyone Provide online resources link for real world example of each (soap and rest) to improve my understanding of those each.

Comment: google might not be new to you , you should try searching these things there , you will get all your answers and if then you face any problem you can come to this portal for getting clarification.

Comment: In soap the request and response format is only in XML format whereas in restful it supports both XML and Json  so any project having XML as I/o is soap and the counterpart is rest is my understanding correct

Answer (score 1):

You can identify by checking wsdl in the project if it has wsdl it means they are using SOAP based webservices.

Where as restful webservices is just a uri mapping in yaml files .

yes you can create a restful webservices using spring framework.

Here you can find

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

https://dzone.com/articles/restful-web-service-1

Please check the above links